# Is "for reasons of moderation" gibberish?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I noticed the following sentence on an otherwise brilliant website:

> This question was removed from English Language & Usage Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/223217/i-can-learn-java-but-cant-program-it-help

Is the phrase "for reasons of moderation" completely lame, or am I linguistically impaired?

Comment: It is, of course, double-talk for "We didn't like that and buried it in a deep hole".  Literally it says "so that something could be moderate", though it doesn't say what that something is.

Comment: The phrase might be based on a template: *"The question was removed from ____ for reasons of ____."* It sounds like the kind of error message that is generated by computer as well as meant to be read by a computer.

Answer (score 3):

*Moderation* refers to managing the content of online forums. It's derived from this verb definition at [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moderation?show=0&t=1422299731)

> to guide a discussion or direct a meeting that involves a group of people

*for reasons of moderation* means that the reason the question was removed was to serve the purpose of managing the content of the web site, i.e. ensuring that it only contains appropriate material.

You could say that it's vacuous, though. It essentially says that the moderators removed it because it was necessary to remove it, but doesn't say why it was considered inappropriate.